# Looking for the best way to re-create the contribution page form using the REST API

Tags: api, contribution-page, rest

I'm pretty new with CiviCRM but not with integrating API's in general.
I'm looking to re-create a contribution form using only the REST API.

Is this even possible?

I had started looking around the API explorer and got the call below.  Not sure if I'm on the right track.

http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=ContributionPage&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"id":2,"api.MembershipBlock.get":{},"api.MembershipType.get":{}}

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?  When you say "recreate a contribution form", do you mean programmatically generate contribution forms in CiviCRM?  Or create a contribution form that exists independently of CiviCRM?

Comment: Also, see this extension, which may help: https://github.com/webaccess/com.webaccessglobal.simpledonate/

Comment: Yes I would like to programmatically generate a contribution form.  The admin would still go in and add/edit the contribution form and details within CiviCRM.  But I'd then like to display that form on a custom php script (outside of Wordpress or Joomla).